# Constraint in SQL Server where value in Col1 can only have a limited choices of values in Col2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

Depending on the value of C1 I want a limited number of choices of strings to be able to insert into Col2.  Code below is included for clarification.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tester]
(
    [C1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [C2] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tester] ([C1], [C2])
VALUES ('ADDRESS', 'Primary')
GO
```

With the string 'address'  I want to only give column2 a choice of the    strings 'primary', 'secondary', 'home'.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tester] ([C1], [C2])
VALUES ('phone', 'home')
GO
```

With the string 'phone' I want to give column2 a choice of only 'leisure', 'work', 'business'.

Comment: What do you mean by 'give column2 a choice...'? Are you saying that you want an error returned when someone tries to insert 'phone' in C1 and, say, 'aliens,' in C2?

Comment: You cannot do that. Use trigger instead

Comment: W3ave, C1 will contain the string 'Address'   I want an error if someone puts the string 'alien' instead of the choices  of 'primary', 'secondary', 'home'.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would have two separate tables `AddressTypes` and `PhoneTypes`, but if you insist, you can use [`CHECK`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx) constraint and write your allowed choices there:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tester](
    [C1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [C2] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tester] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Rules] CHECK 
(
([C1]='address' AND [C2] IN ('home', 'secondary', 'primary')) OR
([C1]='phone' AND [C2] IN ('leisure', 'work', 'business'))
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tester] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Rules]
GO
```

**Test**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tester] ([C1],[C2]) VALUES 
('address', 'home'),
('address', 'primary'),
('phone', 'business');
```

Returns:

```
(3 row(s) affected)
```

But

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tester] ([C1],[C2]) 
VALUES ('phone', 'primary');
```

Returns:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Rules". 
The conflict occurred in database "AdventureWorks2014", table "dbo.tester".
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: We might go with 2 separate tables as you suggested in the beginning.  we are still in the battle with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement and put it in a `TRY CATCH`

As you can see I made the columns in the table to not to accept `NULL` values

```
DECLARE @tester TABLE
(
    [C1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [C2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @col1 VARCHAR(20) = 'ADDRESS' , @col2 VARCHAR(20) = 'work'

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT @tester
    SELECT  CASE  WHEN @col1 = 'address' AND @col2 IN ('primary', 'secondary', 'home') THEN @col1
                  WHEN @col1 = 'phone' AND @col2 IN ('leisure', 'work', 'business') THEN @col1 ELSE NULL END
            ,CASE WHEN @col1 = 'address' AND @col2 IN ('primary', 'secondary', 'home') THEN @col2
                  WHEN @col1 = 'phone' AND @col2 IN ('leisure', 'work', 'business') THEN @col2 ELSE NULL END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH

SELECT * FROM @tester
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the table structure, see the other two answers.

The better way to handle this though, is to create a table containing possible combinations. Example (names could be chosen better):

```
CREATE TABLE contact_cat(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    desc NOT NULL VARCHAR(128),
    CONSTRAINT PK_contact_cat PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE contact_sub(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    desc NOT NULL VARCHAR(128),
    CONSTRAINT PK_contact_sub PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE contact_style(
    cat_id INT NOT NULL,
    sub_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_contact_style PRIMARY KEY(cat_id,sub_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_contact_style_contact_cat FOREIGN KEY(cat_id) REFERENCES contact_cat(id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_contact_style_contact_sub FOREIGN KEY(sub_id) REFERENCES contact_sub(id)
);
CREATE TABLE tester(
    cat_id INT NOT NULL,
    sub_id INT NOT NULL,
    information VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_tester_contact_style FOREIGN KEY(cat_id,sub_id) REFERENCES contact_style(cat_id,sub_id)
);
```

Fill table with cat + sub, then allowed combinations in `contact_style`:

```
INSERT INTO contact_cat(id,desc)VALUES(1,'Address');
INSERT INTO contact_cat(id,desc)VALUES(2,'Phone');
INSERT INTO contact_sub(id,desc)VALUES(1,'Primary');
INSERT INTO contact_sub(id,desc)VALUES(2,'Leisure');
INSERT INTO contact_style(cat_id,sub_id)VALUES(1,1); -- Address + Primary
INSERT INTO contact_style(cat_id,sub_id)VALUES(2,2); -- Phone + Leisure
```

Add information to `tester`:

```
INSERT INTO tester(cat_id,sub_id,information)VALUES(1,1,'NY, 120 Boulevard Av'); -- succeeds
INSERT INTO tester(cat_id,sub_id,information)VALUES(2,2,'555 77 88 99'); -- succeeds
INSERT INTO tester(cat_id,sub_id,information)VALUES(1,2,'Blablabla'); -- fails
INSERT INTO tester(cat_id,sub_id,information)VALUES(2,1,'More blah'); -- fails
```

The first two statements succeed because the foreign keys exist in the allowed contact styles in `contact_style`. The last two fail because the foreign keys don't exist in `contact_style`.

Benefits of this way of working:

- No need have to repeat the contact category + subcategory description each time.
- Saves you disk space, and memory when these tables are cached in memory; tables are cached in SQL Server as much as possible to speed up query response.
- You don't have to rewrite any constraints when new categories, or subcategories are required (cf other answers). Simply add the rows for the new cat/subcat in the appropriate table, add rows to `contact_style` to reflect new combinations and presto.

Comment: PS: Better still would be to store addresses and phone numbers separately.

Comment: TT., You should see the programmers squirm concerning your answer. :)  Because of your suggestion we are considering adding some tables.  The constraint:     CONSTRAINT FK_tester_contact_style FOREIGN KEY(cat_id,sub_id) REFERENCES contact_style(cat_id,sub_id)  made everyone happy.  More to come....

Comment: @user2241789 =) Good to hear, let 'em squirm ;-). I've added one more benefit over using constraints.